# SSRS TimeOut Exception - When Exporting through WCF Service after 1 min 40 sec

Tags: wcf, ssrs-2008-r2

I am facing Time Out Exception when Exporting the SSRS Report to other formats(Excel or PDF) after 100 Sec (1 Min 40 Sec) exactly. Help me out.

Even though i made Some Configuration changes in Report Server and in Config files as below to resolve the Time Out issue but still not resolved.

Please check the below changes and let me need any changes or still some where to change the Configurations.

**1. (Rdl file)Processing option -> Report Time Out -> Do not timeout report**

**2. Changed the configuration in web.Config of Service.**

```
 Set the executionTimeout value to ‘10800’ (3 hours) as shown below:

  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout = "10800" />
  </system.web>
```

**3.** SQL Server Management Studio, connect to a report server instance, right-click the      report server name, and select Properties. Click Execution to open this page. 
Changed to Do not timeout report execution .

**4.   In RSReportServer.config Changed the default values(DatabaseQueryTimeout):**

```
  <Add Key="ProcessRecycleOptions" Value="1"/> <!--Disabled-->

  <Add Key="CleanupCycleMinutes" Value="36000"/> <!--10 Hours-->

  <Add Key="SQLCommandTimeoutSeconds" Value="0"/> <!--None-->

   <Add Key="MaxActiveReqForOneUser" Value="100"/>

  <Add Key="**DatabaseQueryTimeout**" Value="0"/> <!--None-->

   <Add Key="RunningRequestsScavengerCycle" Value="36000"/> <!--10 Hours-->

  <Add Key="RunningRequestsDbCycle" Value="36000"/> <!--10 Hours-->

  <Add Key="RunningRequestsAge" Value="30"/>
```

**5. ExecutionTimeout setting within the web.config**

\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.X\Reporting Services\ReportManager\

and

\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.X\Reporting Services\ReportServer)

In both web.config files i altered to 36000

).

and there is 20min to session timeout value for Application.

**I hope solution for above one.**

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: 1. Does the report run fine when you execute it outside of WCF?  2.  It's possible that the WCF service is encountering an unhandled exception - those *can* show up as timeouts.  Also you may need to adjust the actual WCF time out values (in the '<bindings>' section of the config file).  If you don't have anything defined, the defaults will be used (which off the top of my head I think is 1 minute).

Comment: <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="1200"/>